# IE8 fails upon previewing a flash gallery

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8

Page is [here](http://bit.ly/ejhtEZ)

Firstly, I cannot reproduce this because I only have `IE8` `RC1`.
Secondly, my client gets this:

```
Message: 'null' is null or not an object
Line: 1
Char: 120
Code: 0
```

To reproduce supposedly you have to be on a legit `IE8`, click on anything in the flash and then fill in form fields and hit preview.

If anyone who can reproduce this can look into this, I'd greatly appreciate it.
I would debug and remove scripts one by one and inquire the client after each page edit but my electricity keeps dying ( snowstorm ) so I can't do that level of debugging atm.

Comment: was unable to reproduce in IE 8.0.7600.16385

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`console.log` was being called from Flash.